# Image is not displaying on web page

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

```
<asp:Image ID="Image11"  runat="server" Height="100px" Width="100px" />
```

VB.net code is here

```
  logo_path = Server.MapPath(Request.ApplicationPath & "/" & "Logo" & "/" & img_name)

    da.Dispose()

    dr.Close()

    Image11.ImageUrl = logo_path

    Session("curr_page_path") = logo_path
```

During debugging time the logo_path that is global variable displays the full path of the image with image name but on web page there is no image...

Comment: Does it render the image URL in `<img src="" ...>`?

Comment: Is this code executing on Page_Load event?

Comment: @ Dennis Traub.. I have to run my code on server and <img src ="" HTML tag not asp

Comment: @guiiherme J Santos .. Yes the code is working fine but no image the the variables shows full image path with image name

Comment: But `<asp:Image ...>` will eventually render as HTML, won't it?

Comment: Please see on the html page what you have final render and see why the image is not visible - also why you have confuse us with the dispose/close/session ?

Comment: No need to repost this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16103861/display-dynamic-image-logo-acc-to-user-type-code-has-no-error-but-no-image-on-s

Comment: i am not going to confusing to any.....but in my code there is a variable name logo_path that display the full path of the image during debugging time but on running it displays no image

Comment: If any one has doubt then they can check... its fine without output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Request.ApplicationPath` will be something like `C:\Inetpub\wwwroot`. This is *not* what you want in the browser. The browser needs a URL like `http://www.example.com/Logo/image1.jpg`. Or as the browser knows which web site it is on, just `Logo/image1.jpg` would do.

All you need is

```
Image11.ImageUrl = "Logo/" & img_name
```

Answer (score -1):

hi please change your code as follow

```
 logo_path = Server.MapPath("/Logo") & "/" & img_name
```

Comment: Server.MapPath(".") returns the current physical directory of the file (e.g. aspx) being executed
Server.MapPath("..") returns the parent directory
Server.MapPath("~") returns the physical path to the root of the application
Server.MapPath("/") returns the physical path to the root of the domain name (is not necessarily the same as the root of the application)

Comment: when i m going for debugging for this then logo_path shows full path on cursor hover but on web page no image is visible i do not knw why

Comment: Server.MapPath("~/Logo/" & img_name)  try this.